# How to change the position of scrollbar using HighChart?

Tags: css, highcharts

I have horizontal scrollbar and button in highchart graph and wanted to change the position of either button or scrollbar to make proper visible[image].

This is the code for button generated by Highchart:

```
  <g class="highcharts-button highcharts-button-normal" style="cursor:pointer;stroke-linecap="round" transform="translate(728,10)">
<rect fill="white" class=" highcharts-button-box" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="108" height="32" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="1" style="
        margin-left: 10px;
    "></rect><text x="8" style="font-weight:normal;color:#333333;fill:#333333;" y="20"><tspan>◁ Back to results</tspan></text></g>
```

Please tell me how can I do this, I googled but didn't get any solution.

Comment: Just add some CSS to the button.

Comment: tried to gave but not taking, added code snippet also

Comment: Can you please share a demo link.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m3Lmrk1c/  working here, but same I am putting in solution it is not working properly....

Comment: Sorry. But can not help without looking at the problem. Try to create a demo link of the problem you are facing. Or just try to modify your styles.